# Inverse excel index match

Tags: excel, indexing

I'm having issue to understand if it's possible to reverse and Index match formula to get the column name given a match in a table's coordinate. Let me write an example to make it clear:

[image]

assume I have the table above/image:
I'd like to get the sport each person chose based on the x coordinates in the table.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Best regards
Luca

Comment: Please note that the rows are dynamic, I cannot just do a index match given each row...

Comment: What do you mean with "rows are dynamic". Do you not know where your matrix is located?

Comment: Assume that you know that row n 1 is fixed, stays there. Then it's easy to do INDEX( [column headers], 1,match("x",row1,0) to get the column number.
But now for the example I have 1 2 3 in real life I have names, like John, Paul and Sam. and these names can change; so i need it to be that changes every time I put new names in the rows names

Comment: That does not clarify much at all I'm afraid. Better to include more detail in your OP. Try to include sample data that lays closer to your real-life situation.

Comment: How can upload data/images in comments? Thx

Comment: Don't add details through comments, edit your question!

Comment: done. I've put an "output" column so that i explain the dynamicity, e.g. that names can be rearranged (to avoid what I've explained before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, now that you made your example a bit clearer, try:

[image]

Formula in `I2`:

```
=INDEX(B$1:F$1,MATCH("x",INDEX(B$2:F$6,MATCH(H2,A$2:A$6,0),0),0))
```